# Trying to load Product CSV file

Tags: product

Loading product *file CSV using columns from a product export from magento, system, export, dataflow-profiles*.

After loading, I get an error that states "**no sku**", But i have a sku in that column.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please share ur  import file

Answer (score 0):

It seems that u have not cleared all formatting before uploading CSV, so steps are
1.after having SKU n its corresponding components select all the blank rows n column
2.use shortcut (ctrl-) to delete rows n colums.
3.Now try to upload the updated csv